# How to fix roof shingles that has paint splattered on them?

Tags: paint, roofing, paint-removal

Our painter got paint on our roof shingles when he was spraying our chimney.

The paint is splattered across a 3’ x 3’ area. It is visible from street level.

What is the easiest way to fix this? (We will probably replace the roof in a year or so)

Should we get some matching shingles and nail them over the existing ones?

Should we just paint the shingles to mask the splattered paint?

Should we replace the shingles?

I’m looking for the most economical way and still have the roof look okay.

Comment: Most economical - get that contractor to sort the paint overspray...

Comment: What NOT to do is “get matching shingles and mail them over the existing”—unless you specifically understand roof nailing and roof water flow you will instantly create many leaks.  If you’re replacing in a year anyway I’d use paint to make it less obvious for now.

Answer (score 1):

Properly speaking, this is something the painter should make right.

Since we live in an imperfect world, I'd suggest you get a spray can of somewhat matching paint and give the overspray a bit of overspray. It's not terrible for the shingles and will improve the look from the street.